# Can't get all my ViewModel properties back after the postback -MVC Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

Can't get **all my ViewModel properties** back after the **postback** (After user entered some values on HttpPost)

*There are numerous questions here related to losing data or getting nulls after the postback
I tried some of them and played around on my case, I think the scenario is a bit different,*

Using a **PartialView** or **Editor Templates**(except a list property), Always the returned result properties are null.

In **partialView approach** always all the properties are null, I think maybe I missed a piece.
In the "**custom editor template approach for the type**", I'll have just "EnteredNums" List returned. (Maybe because these are what the template have EditorFor for them, but what is the solution here if that's the case?)

*Don't know weather if it's important here or not, the application also uses Unity. I don't think it be the problem here.*

The **HttpGet** Passed model is the same as HttpPost : `DataVm`

The name of the **action** is also the same : `ProcessEnteredData`

===================  **Controller and action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessEnteredData(DataVm vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (NumType num in vm.EnteredNums)
            {
                int i1 = num.Score1;
                int i2 = num.Score2;
                string profTitle = vm.Profile.Title;
                Repository.Context.EnteredNums.Add(num);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("ShowTable");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(vm);
        }
    }
```

==============
**The Partial View of Custom Editor Template are similar :**

```
@model xxxx.NumType

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TheTitle)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Score1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Score2)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Profile) 
// Profile or ProfileId - Just used to see could it bring the property back or not as a test
```

============
**NumType Model**

```
    [Key]
    public int NumTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Profile")]
    [Required]
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public int Score1 { get; set; }
    public int Score2 { get; set; }     
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public Box Box { get; set; } // something not important here
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
```

============
**`The ViewModel`**

```
public class DataVm
{
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public string TheTitle { get; set; }
    public List<NumType> EnteredNums { get; set; } 
    // In the Editor template approach it's the only item with data and others are null
    public List<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
}
```

=========
**View for PartialView approach :**

```
@model xxxx.DataVm

@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessEnteredData", "Profile", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    Model.EnteredNums = new List<NumType>();
    foreach(var box in Model.Boxes) 
    {
        NumType num = new NumType();
        num.Profile = Model.Profile;
        num.Box = box;

        int iCount = Model.EnteredNums.Count;
        Model.EnteredNums.Add(num);

        @Html.Partial("NumView", Model.EnteredNums[iCount]);
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Do Process" />
}
```

===================
**View for Editor for approach :**
// instead of @Html.Partial :

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.EnteredNums[iCount]);
```

Comment: In situations like that, I usually take baby steps and create a simple side project (which takes 2 minutes) in which I create a simple Controller, simple ViewModel and View. I get the basics working and gently add properties in my ViewModel and in the View while submitting the <form> and hitting the Controller to see what is happening. Eventually, you’ll find the culprit

Comment: Thanks considering my issue, So there wasn't any problem to your eyes?

Comment: For doing some tests, I added a constructor on the viewmodel and saw that it's fired before the HttpPostAction takes place, dont know is it regular or not?! if not why that happens? I didn't instantiate a new object there, maybe a regular procedure of MVC is happening, don't know. Anyway considering that it contains the EnteredNums even after that behavior.